# Is it possible to use Apple Magic mouse's 'pad' for moving the cursor?

Tags: macos, mouse

As the title indicates, I'm interested in being able to move the cursor with the mouse's 'pad'.
What I mean is, am I able to move the cursor without moving the mouse itself (physically)?

Answer (score 1):

BetterTouchTool has Magic Mouse Touchpad Mode.

> assign the predefined action "Magic Mouse Touchpad Mode On / Off" to some trigger in BTT.
>
> [image]

https://community.folivora.ai/t/magicmouse-trackpad-mode-still-available/13538/2